# Overflow horizontal must start at right element AMP only CSS

Tags: css, scroll, overflow, amp-html

I need this overflow horizontal element starts at the right instead of the left.
It contains some `<li>`.
This is my container `<ol>` properties:
    `overflow-x: scroll;
overflow-y: hidden;white-space: nowrap;`

Answer (score 3):

Try `display: flex;` with `flex-direction: row-reverse;`

**Edit:**

For the order issue you can do it like so:

```css
li:nth-child(1) {
  order: 5;
}

li:nth-child(2) {
  order: 4;
}

li:nth-child(3) {
  order: 3;
}

li:nth-child(4) {
  order: 2;
}

li:nth-child(5) {
  order: 1;
}
```

and so on.

If you're using a templating engine, you can do this dynamically.

I hope this helps.

Comment: It happens the same, i don't want to change the order of the elements. But thank you for your answer.

Comment: Then you can change the order again with `order: <number>;`. You're welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Adding `direction: rtl` to your `<ol>` should do the trick. This changes the text direction from left (default) to right therefore the scrollbar starts from the right side.

```css
ol {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  max-width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  direction: rtl;
}

 li {
   display: inline-block;
 }
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>Lorem ipsum.</li>
  <li>Nemo, atque?</li>
  <li>Dicta, perspiciatis!</li>
  <li>Voluptate, fugit!</li>
  <li>Atque, eligendi.</li>
  <li>Voluptate, in!</li>
  <li>Est, a!</li>
  <li>Dolorem, quis.</li>
</ol>
```

**Edit:** If you want to keep the order of your items and still start from right then you'll need to get the scrollWidth of the element and scroll to the end using Javascript like so:

```
var ol = document.getElementById('ol');

ol.scrollLeft = ol.scrollWidth;
```

Comment: But I want to keep the order of the li elements

Comment: I edited my answer with another example to achieve this but using Javascript since I'm not sure that is achieveable using CSS only.

Comment: That would be great, but for AMP can't use javascript, only CSS